# Using redis as a cache for a mysql database

Tags: php, caching, redis

I need to create a solution using php, with a mysql database with lots of data. My program will have many requisitions, I think that if I work with cache and an OO database, I'll have a good result, but I don't have experience.

I think for example if I cache the information that is saved in mysql in a redis database, performance will be improved, but I don't know if this is a good idea, so I would like someone to help me to choose.

Sorry if my English is not very good, I'm from Brazil.

Comment: Are you asking if it is good idea to cache database or not?

Comment: I use redis in front myself, but youmay want to look at `MySQL's`  `HEAP` tables if you are already using `MySQL`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Yes, redis is good for that. But to get the gist, there are basically two approaches to caching. Depending on whether you use a framework (and which) or not, you may have first option available in standard or with use of a plug-in:

1. Cache database queries, that is - selected queries and their results will be kept in redis for quicker access for a given time or until clearing cache (useful after updating databse). In this case you can use built-in mysql query caching, it will be simpler than using additional key-value store, or you can override default database integration with your own class making use of cache (for example http://pythonhosted.org/johnny-cache/).
2. Custom caching, that is creating your own structures to be kept in cache and periodically or manually refilling them with data fetched from the database. It is more flexible and potentially more powerful, because you can use built-in redis features such as lists or sorted sets, which make update overhead much smaller. It requires a bit more of coding, but it usually offers better results, since it is more customized. Good example is keeping top articles in form of redis list of ids, and then accessing serialized article(s) with given id as well from redis. You can keep that article unnormalized - ie. serialized object can contain user id as well as user name, so that you can keep the overhead of additional queries to a minimum.

It is yours to decide which approach to take, I personally almost always go with approach number two. But, of course, everything depends on how much time you have, and what the application is supposed to do - you might as well start with mysql query caching and if the results are not good enough move to redis and custom caching.

Comment: Thank you Krzysztof Bujniewicz

Comment: Thank you Krzysztof Bujniewicz. I will use number two, the database mysql already exists and have much data, so I move a copy to redis and when the user save a new data, the program will save in mysql, when user call a results or reports the program will use redis. What do you think about this? I will use Yii framework. http://www.yiiframework.com/

Comment: try not to copy database 1:1, but rather put there serialized objects, after manipulation on data obtained from mysql, ready to use in application. Good example is keeping top articles in form of redis list of ids, and then accessing serialized article(s) with given id as well from redis.

Comment: Thank you  Krzysztof Bujniewicz. Your information help me to solve the problem.

Comment: I shall upvote thee for introducing me with [Johnny Cache](http://pythonhosted.org/johnny-cache/)

Comment: Is Redis useful only for read operations through caching? That is, read from db may be slow, so Redis makes it faster? What about write operations?

Comment: Depending on the way Redis is set up, it can or cannot be used as a permanent database (by default everything is stored in RAM, but there are various options for writing changes to permanent storage), It makes Redis a lot slower than with default settings because of additional IO operations. There are ways to levarage Redis to do bulk inserts to the database, especially when the data is non-critical (ie. you can lose one second of writes) with creating lists or sorted setrs of items to update in your main database. See http://redis.io/topics/persistence for more about how to set it up.

Comment: Just wanted to add a note to help future readers. Re: option 1, the built-in mysql query caching is highly disrecommended and in fact deprecated as of MySQL 5.7.20, and is removed in MySQL 8.0. https://www.taos.com/understanding-mysql-query-cache/ lists the pitfalls of using it.