# How to connect Redis to MySQL service?

Tags: mysql, redis, zend-framework2

I'm trying to connect Redis to MySQL since Redis doesn't support updating when a db trigger occur, is it possible?

Currently we handle every workaround through php zf2 which is not ideal.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16268950/using-redis-as-a-cache-for-a-mysql-database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16268950/using-redis-as-a-cache-for-a-mysql-database)

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution: you need to use logstash and keep it running to connect both Redis and mySQL in real time.

```
mysql > mysqlfile > filebeat > logstash > redis
```

Where mySQL is the database server. Any changes there goes to the mySQL file.

Filebeat reads the `mysqlfile` using some sort of tail function then filters it to logstash.
logstash sends it to a channel on Redis.

Answer (score 0):

I also facing  same problem.Actually the redis db & mysql db both are different databases.So according to me there is no way to connect redis with mysql.
 but I was solved my problem with cron job. I was run the cron in every minute.. which check the new entry in mysql db and update in redis db...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16268950/using-redis-as-a-cache-for-a-mysql-database